# Flexbox adapt element width to not let white space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to achieve a multi-line flexbox container where element width can reduce if it's min-width is not reach to not let big whitespace when break line happen.
Here is an example on which i'm working on : https://codepen.io/BaptisteG/pen/dyyQodR

```
.container {  
border: 5px solid rgb(111,41,97);
border-radius: .5em;
padding: 10px;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
row-gap: 1em;
column-gap: 20px;
width: 500px;
}

.item {
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: rgba(111,41,97,.3);
 border: 2px solid rgba(111,41,97,.5);
 flex: 1 1 content;
 min-width: 100px;
 max-width: min-content;
 white-space:nowrap;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

A sketch of what i want to achieve :
[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6a1v.png)
I don't want element size to be increase to complete whitespace

Comment: So what is the element that will cause the break supposed to do. I'm unclear n what it is you are trying to achieve. The image doesn't really explain it.

Comment: The element have to be reduce to fit and not let space between element and the container
Except if min-width reach

Comment: That's not possible with CSS. You need javascript.